# Generate URI from String provided by user via command line argument

Tags: java, string, file, uri, command-line-arguments

This is such a simple question, I'm sure the answer is out there and I'm simply not searching with the proper lingo. I'm new to Java, using Java 8, and want to learn how to properly handle this, rather than rigging it together.

The application takes in arguments via command line.

```
$ MyApp /home/user/thefiletheywant.me
```

I have tried the following:

```
// Missing Scheme, I know I can just force ("file:" + args[0]) but is that proper?
URI fileIn = new URI(args[0]);

// I've learned this is the same thing as above
URI fileIn = URI.create(args[0]);
```

I've seen examples that take the string, check with File.Separator to verify it is "/" and if not, replace it, then simply tack on "file:" in front. Which, again, seems sloppy.

- What if the user added "http:"?
- What if the user specifies a full path or a path relative to the directory they are currently in?
- Do the builtin functions verify the path is proper? I'm aware of file.isFile() and file.exists(), which I can check myself easy enough.

If I knew exactly where the file was every time, of course the URI.create would be fine. But for future education, I want to know how to properly handle this very simple scenario. Please forgive me if in my searches I've simply somehow missed what I suspect is an easy solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just create a File object in java, which is OS-independent (Windows uses backslash for instance), check if it exists, and use the handy `toURI()` method on it, to create a valid URI object.

```
File myFile = new File(args[0]);
URI fileUri = null;
if(myFile.exists()) {
    fileUri = myFile.toURI();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the super fast reply. I think I missed that solution early on, then as I read more and more posts I started to severely over think the problem.